# Running Linux Console Application From WINE

Tags: wine

I have a Windows program running on WINE.  I need to invoke a Linux console application from the Windows program.

Although this seems like the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004070/execute-shell-commands-from-program-running-in-wine), none of the answers given there actually work in the case of *non-GUI* applications.  The common answer is:

```
wineconsole cmd
start /unix /usr/bin/gedit
```

This does work, but not for console applications - if you try i.e.:

```
start /unix /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

or

```
start /unix /usr/bin/git
```

Nothing happens. It shows no error, no output, nothing.  Another option is to just create a symlink, like:

```
 ln -s /usr/bin/ffmpeg /path/to/wineprefix/drive_c/ffmpeg.exe
```

...Then run "ffmpeg.exe" from the WINE command prompt. But the behavior is the same: no error, no output.

Is there some way to invoke *non-GUI* (aka console) Linux applications from a Windows application running in WINE?

Comment: This is not a generic Linux support site, you've provided nothing that is specifically on-topic for this site, so why ask here?  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Because I specifically searched for "WINE" before posting & there were hundreds of pages worth of WINE-related questions, so clearly it's a topic that's commonly discussed here; and because this Linux-related StackExchange site has significantly more activity than the other unix.stackexchange, and posting on the more-trafficked site typically has better odds of getting meaningful replies.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: Kubuntu 20.04 (Focal)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK console apps are writing their output to terminal and exit. You need to convince terminal to stay open. Here is a sample with gnome-terminal and bash opening `ffmpeg` with no params:

```
start /unix /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- bash -c "ffmpeg; exec bash -i"
```

Comment: That's not the problem. 1) Since this is all being test run in `wineconsole cmd` (per above), aka the windows command prompt, any output written to the terminal should be shown, whether or not the binary exits after doing its output. 2) A simpler test run of `start /unix /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/ffmpeg; exec bash -i"` behaves the same. I'm not sure about gnome-terminal, but that's not standard against Linux distros - did you try something like the above...?